# Selenium / try to open the aside-element?

Tags: selenium, testing, web-scraping

i try to use selenium on the following webpage and try to open the "Total Revenues" aside-element on the left side -

With this code i am able to open the site and log in (of source this are no real credentials and this is not my general password... :=)

link = "https://www.causeiq.com/search/organizations/so_4ef5f36d1e427557#list"

```
options = Options()
path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)
driver.get (link)
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="top"]/div/div[2]/a').click ()
driver.find_element_by_id("id_login").send_keys("rapid1898@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys("12345678")
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="stage_content"]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/button').click ()
```

Then something in this form is shown:
[image]

Now i want to open the total revenue element on the left side - so it looks like this
[image]

I tried it with this code - but with that these element is not opening like you see it on the picture:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="search_filters_new"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[5]/div')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','new-filter-item active')", element)
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="search_filters_new"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[5]/div').click()
```

Is there any way to do this with selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanna try that with explicit waits :

so once browser is launched with full screen mode  :

do this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Total revenues']"))).click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

do this to launch the browser in full mode :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get (link)
```

Comment: Hello - it seems that this works with your code - thank you.
Just for my unterstanding - with this statement: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) the webdriver will wait maximum 10 seconds until the element is loaded?
I also reduced the time.sleep to 1 seconds - and it also works (it was only necessary that i add the time. before sleep).
But it only waits 1 seconds overall - not the 10 + 1 seconds.

Comment: yes the maximum time to wait is 10 seconds,  and in this 10 seconds WebDriverWait will try to find element after an interval of 500ms. so it will keep retrying until element is found, if yes then return the element , if no raise the Timeout exception

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for "Total Revenues":-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Total revenues']").click()
```

Comment: Hello - i tried this, get no error - but at the end the aside-element on the left side is simply white and empty: https://ibb.co/1nBMKnV